# NU1202 Package is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package does not support any target frameworks

Tags: .net-6.0, nuget-package-restore

My project is now failing to restore Nuget dependencies for some packages, that was wokring just fine in the older version of VS i.e. 2017.

I have started to get the following errors when I am trying to `dotnet build` or `dotnet restore`.

[image]

Could someone please help resolving this.

**The version info:**

- MSBuild version 17.8.5+b5265ef37 for .NET Framework
- VS: 17.8.5 Nuget
- NUGET Package Manger: 6.8.0

[image]